# How to disable TypeScript warnings in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I don't use TypeScript for the time being. Only ES6 with babel.
I don't have installed TypeScript in *node_modules*.

I get a specific warning from VSCode every time I open a workspace.

> `\node_modules\typescript\lib` doesn't point to a valid *tsserver* install. Falling back to bundled TypeScript version.

How can I get rid of such warnings? Or should I change editor in order to feel calm?

Comment: I am still getting ts6133 no-unused-vars, even though I have `// eslint-disable-line`. vscode removes the line on save. I have eslint and eslint vscode extension. I do not have tslint extension.

My user settings:
```
    "eslint.codeActionsOnSave.mode": "all",
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": true,
    "javascript.validate.enable": false,
    "typescript.validate.enable": false,
    "javascript.format.enable": false,
    "typescript.format.enable": false,
    "javascript.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": false,
    "javascript.suggestionActions.enabled": false,
```
Please help!

Comment: **Note:** Depending on what you're wanting, you may want to just disable the built-in Extensions altogether. See [my new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68146666/1599699) for more.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

TypeScript and JavaScript validation can be turned off in VS Code with these two settings:

```json
"typescript.validate.enable": false,
"javascript.validate.enable": false,
```

Comment: Thanks,  after your answer,  I changed this setting and others for TypeScript, but the specific warning is not disappeared. I think the only way is to install in local node_modules  the TypeScript. I can do it, even if I don't use it, but I am afraid not having other warnings later :-)

Comment: Actually, that might a different problem. Some AV software deletes the `tsserver.js` file that we launch to provide features like formatting et al

Comment: It looks for the \node_modules\typescript\lib, but I did not install  the typescript. so there is not such folder.

Comment: @JohannesRieken Why both? Aren't we only interested in disabling TypeScript? You can improve your solution by mentioning what the second statement does, it's pretty confusing given it states to disable JavaScript validation, when we are interested in disabling TypeScript.

Comment: For some reason, I had to disable javascript validation to disable the typescript validation. That is very confusing.

Comment: It's a shame to disable builtin JS+TypeScript validation globally for all and any proiject (even TypeScript ones) just because it cannot be turned off on a 'per project' basis or isn't smart enough to not typescript validate non-typescript files.

Comment: Where do you put these values?

Comment: @Kingamere file > preferences > settings > (top right) show as json

Comment: @simbolo There is no need to turn it off globally for all projects. You can set it just for a single folder/project by creating a `.vscode` directory and adding a `settings.json` file inside of it. If you use a multi-root workspace you open the command palette and search for "workspace settings" and you will notice a separate settings menu item, apart from user settings.

Comment: Some info about why `javascript.validate.enable: false` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52568994/5820158

Comment: This answer disables errors as well along with warnings which may not be the required case

Comment: Downvoted as there must be a way to disable ONLY typescript but not the JavaScript warning/errors. Using only the `"typescript.validate.enable": false` option will still show in the editor warnings with `ts(...)` error codes

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay vscode uses the typescript language server to validate javascript, so "javascript.validate.enable" requires typescript to function. It should be using the built in version of typescript if the project doesn't have a dependency on typescript, so this error is most likely caused by a workspace or user preference that sets the tsc or tsdk path. It's usually from setting the tsc path in the global preferences instead of workspace preferences when working on another project.

Comment: I never have luck finding this in the preferences when my workspace settings get wiped after I run `git-clean` and always have to come here ':)!

Comment: When adding javascript.validate.enable: false ts errors goes away but it also removes the auto import suggestion in the "Quick fix..." - Adding a jsconfig.json didn't solve the auto import issue neither. This must be a bug imo

Answer (score 43):

1. open the command palette : <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. open the file settings.json :

[image]

3. add these 2 lines of code:

   ```
   "typescript.validate.enable": false,
   "javascript.validate.enable": false,
   ```

Comment: This error is almost always caused by accidentally setting the path to the typescript compiler or tsdk library in the user preferences instead of the workspace preferences when working on a typescript project, then switching to a javascript project. If anyone reading this has this problem, try Bernard's answer first and only disable validation if it doesn't work. You probably want to know if your javascript is buggy. :)

Answer (score 15):

As per [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/17068#issuecomment-366923931), you can disable built-in extensions in VSCode now. In the Extensions tab on the left (Ctrl+Shift+X), search for `@builtin`  + `JavaScript` / `TypeScript`. Then click the little gear icon next to an Extension and click `Disable`.

I disabled `TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features` (there is a `JavaScript Language Basics` Extension) and `TypeScript Language Basics`.

Comment: I tried this also, but it also disabled the TS definition files and import navigation, which I did not want turned off.

Answer (score 14):

I was having a similar problem. I had an incorrect setting for `typescript.tsdk` in my user settings:

```
"typescript.tsdk": null
```

To fix it, you can either set the location to a valid location:

```
"typescript.tsdk": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib",
```

or just remove the line from your settings if are not using Typescript.

If you need more detail, I found the [VSCode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions) to be very concise and easy to understand.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's too bad a bunch of people will see the accepted answer and turn off their validation instead.

Comment: The provided link doesn't mention typescript.tsdk (any more??) but this one does: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling

Answer (score 8):

In my case it was caused because there was extension that used `vscode.typescript-language-features` extension.

I still wanted javascript errors to be shown so `"javascript.validate.enable": false,` wasn't an option.

By disabling the extension "VueDX" that was using the @builtin extension it fixed the issue and still shows javascript syntax errors.

You can search all the typescript extensions by searching on `@builtin typescript`

Answer (score 5):

Good answers, but I had a situation where I only wanted to turn off TypeScript validation for some unported vanilla JavaScript that we're using in TypeScript land. Our use of eslint didn't catch nearly as many errors as the TypeScript validator, so to preserve the ability to validate "real" *.ts, it was important to **only turn off TypeScript validation for specific files**.

Easy enough, it turns out. [From bobbyhadz.com](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-disable-type-checking#disable-type-checking-for-an-entire-file-in-typescript):

> Use the `// @ts-nocheck` comment to disable type checking for an entire file in TypeScript.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> // @ts-nocheck
>
> console.log('no errors' / 0);
> console.log('no errors' / 0);
> ```

And [from the TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro-to-js-ts.html#ts-check) (which shows ways to get even more granular):

> You can skip checking some files by adding a `// @ts-nocheck` comment to files.
>
> TypeScript may offer you errors which you disagree with, in those cases you can ignore errors on specific lines by adding `// @ts-ignore` or `// @ts-expect-error` on the preceding line.
>
> ```
> // @ts-check
> /** @type {number} */
> var x;
>  
> x = 0; // OK
> // @ts-expect-error
> x = false; // Not OK
> ```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify a setting, open the settings option (there is a new settings editor by the time I am writing this) and search for the setting you want to modify. I was attempting to change the typescript validation, but I wasn't allowed as the document was read only. If you hover over the setting, you get a pen on the left of the setting. If you right click on the pen, it will give you the option of true or false, as for my case I was targeting `"typescript.validate.enable"`. I changed it to false, which in turn, VS code copied the code into the right of the screen with the new value. In short, the left is the settings.json file. On the right, you have the user-settings.json. You are only allowed to modify the user settings and the user setting can override any settings in the main `settings.json` file. -Kf

[image]