# Removing [ts] errors from JS files In VS Code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I get these TypeScript errors VS Code while I'm working in JS files. Is there anything I can do to disable this? I have put this in my settings and did not solve the issue:

```
"typescript.validate.enable": false
```

The error can been seen here

[image]

Comment: create a `jsconfig.json` and put your settings in there.

Comment: Please include error text as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

There's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/54691)  that discusses the `[ts]` token from the errors in a bit more detail. The most relevant comment to this discussion is:

> Yes. The TypeScript extension powers our javascript intellisense which is why you see `[TS]` in your js file. That only indicates what extension is providing that error.

You can disable this validation itself by adding the following to an appropriate `settings.json` file:

```
"javascript.validate.enable": false
```

The [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript) discusses this option a little bit further:

> With `javascript.validate.enable: false`, you disable all built-in syntax checking. If you do this, we recommend that you use a linter like [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) to validate your source code.

As noted above, this disables *all* built-in syntax checking. Although the suggestion is to use something like [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) instead, there might be another option  if you're *specifically concerned about the `import`/`export` errors*. You can add a `jsconfig.json` file to your project with the following content:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es2015"
    }
}
```

This instructs VS Code to use the es2015 module syntax (`import`/`export`), which appears to make it happier.

Comment: Setting module to es2015 doesn't seem to work in the current version of VS Code.

Comment: This doesn't work in VSCode 1.72.2 at least.

Comment: @knutole Can you provide any extra information? It looks like the `module` setting is no longer needed, so perhaps the problem you have is different...

Comment: I get really annoying squiggly lines in VSCode with all kinds of random, erroneous errors. My project is in JS, not TS, but the errors are all ts1302 etc. I have tried everything listed on this page, but nothing works :/ The "javascript.validate.enable" flag doesn't seem to be active even. When I delete and paste back the code with red squiggly lines, the lines disappear, and VSCode is happy. Quite frustrating tbh :)

Answer (score 38):

On Windows- File > Preferences > Settings
Go to Extensions->TypeScript-> Javascript>Validate
make sure Enable/disable JavaScript validation. is not checked

[image]

Answer (score 30):

This works for me

On Windows- File > Preferences > Settings

[image]

make sure validate is not enable

Comment: Noting that TypeScript is inside the Extensions dropdown

Answer (score 9):

Make sure `javascript.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs` is false VSCode settings.

Answer (score 2):

On visual studio code File > Preferences > Settings Go to Extensions->TypeScript-> Javascript>Validate make sure Enable/disable JavaScript validatio

Answer (score 2):

On the **settings.json** file add a line

```
"js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true,
"javascript.validate.enable": false, // => required
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough information about project setup and code, but it looks like you are trying to load `.js` files as typescript.

To use JavaScript files in Typescript projects you must enable `allowJs` flag, either in command line `--allowJs` or in the `tsconfig.json` as `"allowJs": true`.

But, if the `.js` files should not be part of the TS project but just are in the same directory tree, you need to review your `exclude` and `include` properties of `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 0):

Open settings in your VSC.
To open your user and workspace settings, use the following VS Code menu command:

- On **Windows/Linux** - File > Preferences > Settings
- On **macOS** - Code > Preferences > Settings

  Check if `tslint.jsEnable` is set to `false`

  `// Control whether tslint is enabled for JavaScript files or not.`
  `"tslint.jsEnable": false,`

Set it to ***false*** in **workspace settings** section

[**From the documentation**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint):
**tslint.enable** - enable/disable tslint.
 
**tslint.jsEnable** - enable/disable tslint for `.js` files, default is false.

[image]

Comment: I have looked for `tslint.jsEnable` and could not find it in my settings.

Comment: then try adding it and make it false. You will have default workspace settings, user settings, workspace settings - which one did you check?

Comment: I'm using User Settings. When I add it I get "Unknown configuration setting". Is there a certain extension for this?

Comment: note that his error has `[ts]` prefix not `[tslint]` so the error comes from typescript compiler not from tslint.

Answer (score 0):

Arrived late, but I was looking for an inline solution when came across on this thread. Found this one which might come handy for someone in similar situation.

```
// @ts-ignore
someCode(withTSError, inIt);
```

Here's the [link to the related github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95538) in case of need!