# Ignore all errors in a typescript file

Tags: typescript

I have a large typescript file that I've inherited. The compiler has many complaints with this file, however it works just fine.

I'll come back to it, but is there any way to suppress all warnings/errors in a specific file?

Answer (score 194):

You can use `// @ts-nocheck` at the top of the file
Files
[image]

Look how its done in the code above.

---

**UPDATE (2024):** If you are getting the `Do not use "@ts-nocheck" because it alters compilation errors.` message, then try adding the following line:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
// @ts-nocheck
```

Check references.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7/ https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Type-Checking-JavaScript-

Comment: This worked for me also, I had some bad package-lock.json issue.

Comment: A bit of history about that: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26887

Comment: Make sure you have at least version `3.7` of typescript to get this feature.

Comment: I tried adding this and got `Do not use "@ts-nocheck" because it alters compilation errors. (eslint@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment)`

Comment: @briancaffey I seemed to have similar problem. In my case they were ts-lint warnings. I later found I was able to suppress them with something like: `public fooBar: any; // eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any`.

Comment: The destination of that last link gives a permission error.

Answer (score 58):

- You can suppress errors in .ts files using `// @ts-ignore` comments
  for lines
- or use `// @ts-nocheck` after version 3.7 for the whole file.

Comment: `// @ts-nocheck` was added in TS version 3.7 see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59631754/4323201

Comment: This was superb..nothing was working for me but it did.Thanks

Comment: `// @ts-nocheck` has to be at the top of the file before the imports.

Answer (score 10):

This is a little known trick. 2 steps:

1. add this triple slash comment to the top of your file

```
/// <reference no-default-lib="true"/>
```

2. toggle this option:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Side note, as of 2019.4.11, `skipDefaultLibCheck` option is marked as DEPRECATED in the [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), but the feature still exists in source code, see [this line](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/ff959096df8cbc3ba6ea95e700b2786390903c5b/src/compiler/utilities.ts#L8634).

Comment: How about for an autogenerated file? Is there a way to disable type checking of the the file without modifying the file itself?

Comment: @DomVinyard Did you ever find a solution for this case?

Comment: @JH- no I'm afraid not, I found a way to remove the errors

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [loose-ts-check](https://github.com/Gelio/loose-ts-check) to filter out and ignore some or all TypeScript errors in specific files.

It's used like this after initial setup:

```
tsc --noEmit | npx loose-ts-check
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Astro (and vanilla JS) you can add `// @ts-nocheck` to the top of the `<script>` tag (the client side script) to silence all the Typescript errors in your `.astro` files. It saves from adding `// @ts-ignore` to each line.

```js
<script>
  // @ts-nocheck
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []
  // other GA nonsense...
</script>
```