# Can I run TestCafe tests with unused Typescript page objects

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, pageobjects

I'm writing tests in TestCafe using Page Objects pattern.

Some of the page objects are written beforehand (before they are actually used), since I know the page and know what to expect.

But, when trying to run tests with unused page objects I will get an error message like:

```
Error: TypeScript compilation failed.
C:/path-to/a.page-object.ts (40, 7): 'PageObjectExample' is declared but never used.
```

Is there a TestCafe or TypeScript option to (temporarily) allow for the compilation of these kinds of tests?

Comment: Do you also have eslint checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are using a custom tsconfig because this error occurs due to the `noUnusedLocal` option. Get rid of this option in your config.

See also:

[Ignore all errors in a typescript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55632954/ignore-all-errors-in-a-typescript-file)

[Customize TestCafe Compiler Options](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/concepts/typescript-and-coffeescript.html#customize-compiler-options)