# Is it possible to run typescript and execute the resulting javascript, ignoring the errors?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to convert a typescript file to javascript. if there are errors, I want to see them, but still run the resulting javascript.

I tried to do these cases:

**1. tsc file.ts && node file.js** - if file.ts has errors I see it, but javascript file does not execute

**2. ts-node file.ts** - the same

**3. tsc-silent -p tsconfig.json --suppress @ file.ts && node file.js** - javascript execute, but I don't see errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore all errors in a typescript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55632954/ignore-all-errors-in-a-typescript-file)

Comment: @scrappedcola No, please read more than just the title. I want to see all errors, but also I want to execute javascript

Comment: Though not an answer to your question but as your project grows `tsc` compilation times get realy big. Consider running tsc for typechecking only (--noEmit) and some transpiler swc/webpack/parcel in parallel for actual code generation. That may greatly reduce your change/recompilation/result times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really more of a shell question - in shells like bash, the `&&` operator only runs the next command in a chain if the previous command exited with a code 0. `tsc` exits with a non-zero code when there are compilation errors, so execution would halt at the `&&` operator. However, you can run a series of commands unconditionally by separating them with semicolons, ignoring and discarding any exit codes earlier in the chain.

`tsc file.ts ; node file.js` should do it, presuming that tsc actually produces a file.js output.

Given this invalid .ts file:

```js
const foo = "x";
foo = 1;
console.log(foo);
```

```sh
$ tsc test.ts ; node test.js
# ▼ errors from compilation
test.ts:2:1 - error TS2588: Cannot assign to 'foo' because it is a constant.

2 foo = 1;
  ~~~


Found 1 error.

1  # <-- output from the executed compiled script
```

Answer (score 0):

In tsconfig.json file set these properties as follows

```json
"moduleResolution": "bundler",
"resolveJsonModule": true
```