# How to ignore TypeScript errors with @ts-ignore?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have a case where I'm importing a pure JavaScript library within a TypeScript project and it is giving me the error `Could not find a declaration file for module xxx`.

After reading I found I can suppress that with a comment `@ts-ignore`. Yet upon adding that comment before the offending line I get another error:

```
Do not use "// @ts-ignore" comments because they suppress compilation errors  @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore
```

How can I fix this error and suppress the original message?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

You can stop using `@ts-ignore`

Or you can disable the eslint rule. Add that in your eslint config (`.eslintrc` or equivalent)

```
...
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore": "off"
  }
...
```

**EDIT:** If you are using `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` version 2.18 or higher, the rule is called `ban-ts-comment` and you need to add

```
"@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment": "off"
```

instead. Here is the [changelog](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2180-2020-01-27)

Comment: I'm just happy to see that name change because working in a shared library where everyone dips their hands in the jar and doesn't check this stuff - meanwhile, I'm busted on missing rule names? good times

Comment: also notice the "allow-with-description" option

Comment: This is a bad practice to disable the rule globally. Instead, disable the rule locally as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67090871/8318744)

Comment: "It's bad practice". So why don't we add a rule to disable disabling this rule, call it "@typescript-eslint/ban-disabling-typescript-eslint-ban-ts-comment", so when I need to use @ts-ignore, I have to prefix it with "// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-disabling-typescript-eslint-ban-ts-comment", surely that will make my code more aesthetic and pleasant to read

Answer (score 195):

All answers here suggest disabling the whole eslint rule which is not very practical, a better solution will be to ignore the eslint error at that specific location like this:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
// @ts-ignore
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution is more flexible and you can still have the global eslint rule

Comment: This is the recommended way instead of accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, but on a side note, I'm the only one that thinks this is ridiculous? How long before there is another rule needed above these two? 

Comment: This is the recommended way than applying globally

Comment: just
// eslint-disable-next-line

Comment: @AgustinAmato this is not recommended because it disables all rules except for disabling just one. And a well-configured linter should not allow that.

Answer (score 50):

Posting as an answer instead of comment to the accepted answer because of my lack of reputation. I still want to contribute and possibly help someone out.

The rule for me was

```
@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
```

not `ban-ts-ignore`

Comment: Thanks for the help. The answer to the original question was `ban-ts-ignore`, but you can  have the issue with `ban-ts-comment` too

Comment: searched many places for this, thanks! top answer is wrong also

Comment: This worked for me after updating to a more recent version of eslint

Answer (score 40):

I recommend allowing `@ts-ignore` with an enforced description. This can be achieved by the following config in `.eslintrc.js`. [Link to documentation](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-ts-comment.md#allow-with-description)

```
rules: {
  '@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment': [
    'error',
    {'ts-ignore': 'allow-with-description'},
  ],
},
```

You are now required to add a `description` for the ignore. This is done by adding a colon `:` after the ignore statement and adding the description (this can also have an enforced *min length minimumDescriptionLength*).

Example:

```
// @ts-ignore: Testing invalid input
```

The description, in this case, would be `Testing invalid input`

Comment: Even the documentation you linked, did not detail the syntax you have here - Thanks!!

Comment: i think instead of adding more and more exceptions lines one above the other this is the way to go, allow @ts-ignore but with a clear description of why it is used.

Answer (score 8):

Since TypeScript 3.9, [`@ts-expect-error`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#-ts-expect-error-comments) can be used.

> When a line is preceded by a // @ts-expect-error comment, TypeScript will suppress that error from being reported; but if there’s no error, TypeScript will report that // @ts-expect-error wasn’t necessary.

The [`@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/ban-ts-comment/) rule allows this kind of comment by default as long as a description is provided explaining the reason.

For example:

```
// @ts-expect-error: No declaration file for module
import something from 'somemodule';
```

---

As an aside, to specifically resolve the error regarding a missing declaration file for a module, if there is truly no types definition to install from [Definitely Typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) (e.g. `@types/module_name`), then you can [declare the module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#shorthand-ambient-modules) in any `.d.ts` file in the project to suppress the error.

```
declare module 'module_name';
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No maddening arms-race of check-disabling comments? Encourages people to include more context when they choose to bypass TS checks? No configuration changes required? What's not to like, this is great, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If running the application using `npm` then the rules can be specified in `package.json`. The syntax is rather different from the other answers:

```json
 "eslintConfig": {
    . . .
    "rules": {
      "ban-ts-comment": 0
    },
    . . .
 }
```

And I confirm using `ban-ts-comment`instead of `ban-ts-ignore` (tested only with `typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin v2.33.0`)