# How to ignore typescript linter errors/warnings "no overload matches this call" when passing react props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've changed my .js file to .tsx and am getting errors in a component:

```
    <ReactJoyride
        ... // other props 
        scrollDuration={scrollDurationState} // gives error
    />
```

I understand the error, which is as follows:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Props | Readonly<Props>): ReactJoyride', gave the following error.
      ...
Property 'scrollDuration' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<ReactJoyride> & Readonly<Props> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.ts(2769)
(JSX attribute) scrollDuration: number
```

Now, I know that the error means that the prop I'm trying to provide to the component doesn't exist on the type definitions for the parameters for the `ReactJoyride` component. I believe this is a problem with the type file for the component, as when I comment the prop out, the behaviour of the component changes.

So I have a situation where I want to ignore the linter error. I've added a line above the error:

```js
// @ts-ignore
```

But now this line is flagged with the warning:

```
Do not use "@ts-ignore" because it alters compilation errors.eslint@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
```

I don't if there's something else I should be doing? I imagine I should specify what error I want to ignore, but the error message doesn't seem to be giving me a recognisable error string. Also I can't find the error reference number (`.ts(2769)`) to match it to anything? I've looked on Microsoft's [diagnostic.Message.json](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v1.6.2/src/compiler/diagnosticMessages.json) file, for example, and it isn't included on there?

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59729654/how-ignore-typescript-errors-with-ts-ignore