# How to turn off error TS2367: This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types 'true' and 'false' have no overlap

Tags: typescript

How do I turn ignore or turn off this error or make it a warning instead of an error?

My app will not compile if because of it.

> TS2367: This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types
> 'true' and 'false' have no overlap.

Here is an [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/G4QwTgBAlgdgxgGwK4BMCmAVNBnALgSRgDMB7CAXglzCTQG4BYAKFElx1wogCJvGnmUIhAAUsRKkwdCpcuSIgE2NAEoIAb2YRt7PF26xSfZgF8gA):

```
var includeTestInfo = true;
var test = "";

if (includeTestInfo==false) {
  test = "test";
}
```

It looks like, ignoring a specific error is an [open feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19139)?

Similar but not the same post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59729654/how-ignore-typescript-errors-with-ts-ignore).

Some suggestions garnered from this post:

- tsconfig.json option to ignore specific errors
- tsignore comment with option to ignore error code
- tsconfig.json to convert specific error to a warning
- typescript to support warnings
- typescript to globally track all errors in external file folder not embedded inline (summary from comments in github issue)
- add or link to solutions for errors from code comments

I argue that this is not a valid error. I disagree with "Typescript is correct here". This is a warning not an error. And I've argued that typescript should have warnings. It's not an error because I do not want to run that test I have in my code and in the most recent case (the third occurrence) it's scaffolding code that will arrive later.

For now, I want to put the if statement behind a flag and flags are valid component of programming.

In fact, Typescript itself states, "This comparison appears to be unintentional..." No Typescript, it's intentional; you're misinterpreting the code and it's not compiling because of that.

Comment: You can always ignore it with a @ts- comment, but what it tells you is that the comparison is pointless (or the type is wrong).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how ignore typescript errors with @ts-ignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59729654/how-ignore-typescript-errors-with-ts-ignore)

Comment: Please read [ask] and share what you have tried.

Comment: Typescript is correct here. Typescript _knows_ that `includeTestInfo` can only be `true`. So the comparison to `false` will never execute. It's dead code. In fact, if you assign something that could be `false` in that scope the error vanishes. https://tsplay.dev/N7qz4W. This seems like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What exactly is it that you think this will allow to you do that you cannot currently do?

Comment: I see I can use @ts-ignore but as was mentioned, that ignores all messages, correct? Is there a way to ignore the specific error mentioned in the op?

Comment: @AlexWayne typescript is being helpful but it's overreacting, not in the message but in calling it an error and preventing it from compiling. In my app I want the option to show debug information. I have created a flag for it. If true, I show debug information and no error is thrown. If set to false, then that should be ok too but ts prevents compilation.

Comment: Why not just avoid this altogether by not comparing it with a boolean literal value? `if (!includeTestInfo) ...`

Comment: @AlexWayne that works, for now, but I disagree with the philosophy behind this error. Imho this should be a warning not an error. And I shouldn't have to change my code style. With your suggestion, I realize I ran into this issue last year. What if TS next developers see your comment and decide to catch that condition, `(!includeTestInfo)`? The app fails to compile and a new bug emerges where there wasn't one to begin with. but I won't change your mind or others, which is why i ask for how to disable the error.

Comment: I don't believe that TypeScript has warnings, just errors. And you can't ignore a _specific_ type error on a line, but allow others. Lastly the TypeScript teams takes backwards compatibility very seriously, your proposed change is _very_ unlikely. Like many things TypeScript the semantics have tradeoffs.

Comment: "TypeScript is correct here." t's correct in identifying a case that will never happen in normal code execution but if I'm stepping through the debugger I can set this variable to true. Or if I am working on the app I can turn this on and see debug info. It is correct in defining the case, it's incorrect in preventing me from compiling the app because of it. Having said that, thank you, I can ignore that line or use your suggestions.

Comment: "My app will not compile if because of it." Wait, why not?  Don't turn on [`--noEmitOnError`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noEmitOnError) and just let your app compile even with the error.  The error should *stay* because it's indicative of dead/silly code, which presumably you'll clean up after whatever debugging you're doing.  You can consider the error the same as a `/**FIXME**/` comment.  What is the use case that requires TS allow the comparison indefinitely with no error?  Maybe I'm missing it.

Comment: @jcalz I think the use case is to ship code with a debug flag constant set to off, which a developer can then turn on, but never commit, in order to enable complex debugging logic or verbose logging. I believe the use case has merit, even if it's not the way I would typically structure things.

Answer (score 6):

TypeScript is correct here. TypeScript *knows* that `includeTestInfo` can only be `true`.

This:

```
var includeTestInfo = true;
```

Creates a variable of type `boolean`, but that type is narrowed to `true` in this scope since TypeScript knows there are no other assignments to it.

You then do:

```
if (includeTestInfo === false) ...
```

And TypeScript knows that `true` will never be `false` and thinks this is likely a mistake.

---

Disabling type errors is usually a bad idea. It's better to fix this properly.

A functionally equivalent snippet of code is this:

```
var includeTestInfo = true;
var test = "";

if (!includeTestInfo) { // fine
   test = "info";
}
```

This has no warnings because TypeScript always allows truthy/falsy checks even if it knows a variable to be truthy/falsy. This lets you work around this quirk of type narrowed boolean values.

And it could argued that 99% of the time comparing boolean values to boolean literals is not advised anyway, but that drifts into opinion, so I will refrain from opining.

---

Or your could assert the `true` `as boolean`, which would prevent the compiler from narrowing the value's type down to `true`.

```
var includeTestInfo = true as boolean;
var test = "";

if (includeTestInfo === false) { // fine
   test = "info";
}
```

But that's a bit kludgy.

---

Lastly, it should be noted that this is a quirk of how TypeScript implicitly narrows the `boolean` type.  The same is not true for string, for instance:

```
var includeTestInfo = 'a';
var test = "";

if (includeTestInfo === 'b') { // fine
   test = "info";
}
```

There's probably a GitHub issue that explains this difference and why it exists, which I'm failing to find at the moment.