# lint error: 'post' is defined but never used

Tags: reactjs, typescript, lint

I have this import:

```
import { post } from '@loopback/rest'
```

and this is how I use it:

```
export class MyClass {
  @post('/example/test', {})
}
```

But I'm getting a lint error: `'post' is defined but never used`, how can I fix this without updating my codebase, is there a lint comment for this?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51145180/how-to-use-ts-ignore-for-a-block

Comment: For those unaware (and unable to search for an "@" symbol... :/). What does the `@post(...)` line do?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an error of a typescript-eslint. According to this [comment](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/5525#issuecomment-1226256085), try updating typescript-eslint to the latest version.