# Nuxt3 - Ignore Type checking for few files

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm working on a Nuxt3 project, and I want to ignore type checking for few files. I use UnoCSS and for UnoCSS configuration I create `unocss.config.ts` file and in this config file I extend the `fontSize` but it gave type error.
Anyone knows how can I ignore few files for type checking?

[image]

I also add exclude `unocss.config.js` in `tsconfig.json`

Here's the `tsconfig.json` code

```json
{
  // https://v3.nuxtjs.org/concepts/typescript
  "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": [
    "unocss.config.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put `// @ts-nocheck` at the top of the file, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59046041/8816585).

PS: Otherwise, renaming it to `.js` doesn't work? Not sure.