# Ignore specific tslint error on visual studio code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I developed a TsLint rule for my team so that we don't forget to remove the `fdescribe()` calls in unit tests before committing.

On WebStorm, everything is fine. But on Visual Studio Code (with official tslint extension), a big error is displayed until the `fdescribe()` is removed, which is annoying.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio Code to ignore this TsLint error ?

[image]

Comment: Well you ask the linter to spot that error, you kind of ask to highlight it ... Not sure you can remove it unless you remove the rule (let it be in the tsconfig file or with a comment)

Comment: @trichetriche I actually want `ng lint` to spot it and fail the PR but I don't want the IDE to show it.

Comment: Could this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632215/how-to-disable-typescript-warnings-in-vscode

Comment: Then you should remove the TSLint extension and use something like [husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky) to use git prepush hooks.