# Typescript iIntellisense not working in Visual Studio Code for Angular 8.0?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, angular8, intellisense

I am using Visual Studio Code and having some issues while coding. A popup came out and asks

`Pop Up : typescript/javascript enable or disable ?`

I disabled that. But after that typescript is not showing errors and Intellisense in my project.

I searched but did not find any solution to this issue.Moreover typescript extension is not showing in the extensions tab in Visual Studio Code Setting.

Here is my code which is not displaying any error even after I added `6531651` in my code at last line.

[image]

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42633555/2674883)

Comment: No it did't worked .