# Why does VS Code throw "Cannot find module 'typescript'. ts(2307)" while the module is there?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, node-modules

I'm using `import * as ts from "typescript";` to import typescript in a .ts file.

The file runs fine, but VS Code is telling me `Cannot find module 'typescript'. ts(2307)`.

Is there any way to suppress this problem?

Edit: **the file can be compiled and run successfully**

Comment: Is typescript installed as a global package?

Comment: @Saddy Yes, it was installed with -g. Might be something else wrong

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548734/tsc-throws-ts2307-cannot-find-module-for-a-local-file

Comment: @Saddy running `tsc file.ts` doesn't throw any error... The error only shows in VS Code's Problems tab

Comment: Sorry about that, this may be able to help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632215/how-to-disable-typescript-warnings-in-vscode

Comment: @Saddy No problem at all! Thanks a lot. This one helps

Comment: Great! I put it as an answer choice. Please mark it as correct so others can find it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to change these two settings in VS Code's settings.json:

```
"typescript.validate.enable": false,
"javascript.validate.enable": false,
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632215/how-to-disable-typescript-warnings-in-vscode)

Answer (score 0):

To make the previous solution more clear.

[Find Edit in  VS Preferences/Settings settings.JSON in ESLint or TSLint or Typescript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNsO8.png)

[settings.json example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Uc06.png)

```
{
    "javascript.format.enable": false,
    "typescript.validate.enable": false,
}
```