Prevent TypeScript errors in VS Code when editing Flow file
I'm editing a Flow file. But VS Code recognises some of the syntax, and thinks it's TypeScript that should be in a TypeScript (.ts) file. As a result, the file is full of red wiggly line source annotations.

What do I have to get VS Code to stop trying to typecheck my files as TypeScript?
I'm not sure if what I'm seeing is an extension or some built in behaviour.
(I do want TypeScript checking in other projects - just not this folder.)

You can try excluding this file in tsconfig.json in the exclude section.

Thanks, I tried that, it didn't work. This worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632215/how-to-disable-typescript-warnings-in-vscode
